# Is it possible to get multiple ID's with document.querySelector()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to find more than one ID (e.g. div1, div2, div3) by using document.querySelector()?

If not then is there a alternative solution?

Comment: Try to use a class instead of ID.

Comment: The `.querySelector()` API only returns one element. You'd want to use `.querySelectorAll()`, which returns a node list.

Comment: so you are simply asking if we can select 3 element at the same time ... which obvious and trivial using comma

Comment: Posting this because it is related, and this question was first result of my google search: `var el = document.querySelector( "#main, #basic, #exclamation" );`

"After executing the above code, el contains the *first* element in the document whose ID is one of main, basic, or exclamation." From the docs, because this is exactly what I needed (saves me an IF clause)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can by do that. First of all, in order to retrieve *multiple* elements, you'll have to use `querySelectorAll`. Second, you just separate all the ids with commas, it's no different from CSS.

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#a, #b, #c');
```

This will give you a `NodeList` of all the elements matching the IDs.

Comment: it's not working on ckeditor
check below code
 ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelectorAll( '#editor','#editor1' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh it should probably be `document.querySelectorAll('#editor, #editor1')` or you're trying to select the elements with those ids before the ckeditor has been initialized.

Comment: Note the fact that you have to provide a single argument to querySelectorAll. e.g. document.querySelectorAll('#a, #b, #c');... NOT document.querySelectorAll('#a', '#b', '#c');. I thought it was the latter and this was not obvious to track down.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var res = document.querySelectorAll("#div,#par,#head");
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
 res[i].style.backgroundColor = '#DCDCDC'
}
```

```html
<div id='div'>div</div>
<p id='par'>paragraph</p> 
<h1 id='head'>Heading</h1>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Answer (score -1):

For those like me who wants to get this list, but doesn't know in advance the elements, you can use this query:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="div"]');
```

This will return the elements with the id div1, div2 and div3 in this case.

The you can iterate throught them using a for loop:

```
    const elements = doc.querySelectorAll('[id^="div"]');
    if (elements.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            const element = elements[i];
            console.log(element.id);
        }
    }
```

Change the console.log() for anything you want.