# querySelector (GetElementByID) - Multiple IDs

Tags: javascript

i have function to convert gregorian dates to jalali date,its work for one  tag,but i have unspecified number of this tags in one page, and it must convert all of theme.

i know getElementById supports one name at a time, and im trying querySelector and getElementsByClassName but its not working

```js
function gregorian_to_jalali(gy, gm, gd) {
  g_d_m = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334];
  if (gy > 1600) {
    jy = 979;
    gy -= 1600;
  } else {
    jy = 0;
    gy -= 621;
  }
  gy2 = (gm > 2) ? (gy + 1) : gy;
  days = (365 * gy) + (parseInt((gy2 + 3) / 4)) - (parseInt((gy2 + 99) / 100)) + (parseInt((gy2 + 399) / 400)) - 80 + gd + g_d_m[gm - 1];
  jy += 33 * (parseInt(days / 12053));
  days %= 12053;
  jy += 4 * (parseInt(days / 1461));
  days %= 1461;
  if (days > 365) {
    jy += parseInt((days - 1) / 365);
    days = (days - 1) % 365;
  }
  jm = (days < 186) ? 1 + parseInt(days / 31) : 7 + parseInt((days - 186) / 30);
  jd = 1 + ((days < 186) ? (days % 31) : ((days - 186) % 30));
  return [jy, jm, jd];
}

const dateElement = document.querySelector('date')
const year = Number(dateElement.dataset.year) // "2019"
const month = Number(dateElement.dataset.month) // "2"
const day = Number(dateElement.dataset.day) // "6"
dateElement.textContent = gregorian_to_jalali(year, month, day).join('/')
```

```html
<date data-year="2019" data-month="5" data-day="7"></date>
<date id="date" class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="7"></date>
<div id="date" class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="8"></div>
<div id="date" class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="9"></div>
<div id="date" class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="10"></div>
```

Comment: You should have only unique id's. It would be better to change `id="date"` to `class="date"`and then you can use `querySelectorAll` to select all tags you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708133/is-it-possible-to-get-multiple-ids-with-document-queryselector/49708159#49708159

Comment: Your query is looking for `date` tags, which don't exist. You mean `[type=date]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code:

- There is no such thing as a `date` element. You should use a `div` instead.
- An `id` (identifier) must be unique to its element, it cannot be repeated on other elements. Instead, you should use a `class`. At the moment you have a `date` class on all your elements expect the first. Thus, if you add the `date` class to your first element. Once you have done that you can use [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to get all the elements on your page which have the class `date`.

  `document.getElementsByClassName()` will return a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), and thus you can turn it into an array using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`). Turning your collection into an array will allow you to loop over it using [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Using `.forEach` you can access every element with the class `date`, which you can then use to pull it's `data-*` attributes from.

See working example below:

```js
function gregorian_to_jalali(gy, gm, gd) {
  g_d_m = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334];
  if (gy > 1600) {
    jy = 979;
    gy -= 1600;
  } else {
    jy = 0;
    gy -= 621;
  }
  gy2 = (gm > 2) ? (gy + 1) : gy;
  days = (365 * gy) + (parseInt((gy2 + 3) / 4)) - (parseInt((gy2 + 99) / 100)) + (parseInt((gy2 + 399) / 400)) - 80 + gd + g_d_m[gm - 1];
  jy += 33 * (parseInt(days / 12053));
  days %= 12053;
  jy += 4 * (parseInt(days / 1461));
  days %= 1461;
  if (days > 365) {
    jy += parseInt((days - 1) / 365);
    days = (days - 1) % 365;
  }
  jm = (days < 186) ? 1 + parseInt(days / 31) : 7 + parseInt((days - 186) / 30);
  jd = 1 + ((days < 186) ? (days % 31) : ((days - 186) % 30));
  return [jy, jm, jd];
}


const dateElements = document.getElementsByClassName("date"); // get all elements with the class "date"
[...dateElements].forEach(function(dateElement) { // loop through each element, where dateElement is the current node
  const year = Number(dateElement.dataset.year);
  const month = Number(dateElement.dataset.month);
  const day = Number(dateElement.dataset.day);
  dateElement.textContent = gregorian_to_jalali(year, month, day).join('/');
})
```

```html
<div class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="5" data-day="7"></div>
<br />
<div class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="7"></div>
<br />
<div  class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="8"></div>
<br />
<div class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="9"></div>
<br />
<div class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="10"></div>
```

Comment: is there anyway to use this snippet to the json file?
for example inside this :
  "date": [
   {
    "startDate":"2019,2,8",
    "endDate":"209,2,10",
   },
   {
    "startDate":"2019,2,8",
    "endDate":"209,2,10",
   },
   {
    "startDate":"2019,2,8",
    "endDate":"209,2,10",
   },
   {
    "startDate":"2019,2,8",
    "endDate":"209,2,10",
   },
]

Comment: @MohammadrezaAhmadpour you can create this as an object. But you can't add it to a json file using javascript (unless you're running your js on a server).

Answer (score 0):

You made mistakes in your code, also in the DOM, you do not have two elements with the same identifier.
The querySelector returns that the first element found, you must instead use querySelectorAll which will return you an array.

```js
function gregorian_to_jalali(gy,gm,gd){
 g_d_m=[0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334];
 if(gy > 1600){
  jy=979;
  gy-=1600;
 }else{
  jy=0;
  gy-=621;
 }
 gy2=(gm > 2)?(gy+1):gy;
 days=(365*gy) +(parseInt((gy2+3)/4)) -(parseInt((gy2+99)/100)) +(parseInt((gy2+399)/400)) -80 +gd +g_d_m[gm-1];
 jy+=33*(parseInt(days/12053)); 
 days%=12053;
 jy+=4*(parseInt(days/1461));
 days%=1461;
 if(days > 365){
  jy+=parseInt((days-1)/365);
  days=(days-1)%365;
 }
 jm=(days < 186)?1+parseInt(days/31):7+parseInt((days-186)/30);
 jd=1+((days < 186)?(days%31):((days-186)%30));
 return [jy,jm,jd];
}

var dateElement = document.querySelectorAll('.date');
for(var i = 0; i < dateElement.length; i++) {
  const year = Number(dateElement[i].dataset.year); // "2019"
  const month = Number(dateElement[i].dataset.month); // "2"
  const day = Number(dateElement[i].dataset.day); // "6"
  dateElement[i].textContent = gregorian_to_jalali(year, month, day).join('/');
}
```

```html
<div class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="5" data-day="7"></div>
<hr>
<div class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="7"></div>
<hr>
<div class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="8"></div>
<hr>
<div class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="9"></div>
<hr>
<div class="date" data-year="2019" data-month="2" data-day="10"></div>
```