# Excluding an additional id from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, button, menu, hide, display

Is it possible to add an id to this code, so that it doesn´t trigger when the desired container itself (mobile-navigation) is clicked PLUS an additional id (hamburger-menu-div). I have a button to trigger the navigation (hamburger-menu-div). It toggles a class. So when I click that specific button, this code should do nothing... Is that possible or do I have a thinking error here?

```js
//Actual code and working but how to insert an additional id to avoid triggering it also on that id

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  var container = document.getElementById('mobile-navigation');
  if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
    container.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

//Changed to this code to select multiple ids but not working

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  var container = document.querySelectorAll('mobile-navigation, hamburger-menu-div');
  if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
    container.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

Thanks for your support!

EDIT: PLACING IN SOME MORE CODE FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING:

```js
//Toggle nav menu to show and hide

document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-div").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mobile-navigation");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
});


//Hide it when clicked outside

var container = document.querySelectorAll('#mobile-navigation, #hamburger-menu-div');
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  var set = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
    if (e.target == container[i]) {
      set = 1;
    }
  }
  if (set === 0) {
    container[1].style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
.hamburger-menu-div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

.mobile-navigation {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 250px;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburger-menu-div" class="hamburger-menu-div">
  BUTTON
</div>


<div id="mobile-navigation" class="mobile-navigation">
  <p>- Navigationpoint 1</p>
  <p>- Navigationpoint 2</p>
  <p>- Navigationpoint 3</p>
  <p>- Navigationpoint 4</p>
  <p>- Navigationpoint 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you might want to go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Comment: Sorry, but I can´t see any example there where they put in multiple ids. It doesn´t help me... :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708133/is-it-possible-to-get-multiple-ids-with-document-queryselector

Comment: Edited code. Still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know If this was not what you wanted. It seems from your code you want to hide the element that was *not* clicked, correct?

```js
var container = document.querySelectorAll('#mobile-navigation, #hamburger-menu-div');
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  //console.log(container);
  for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
    if (!(container[i].contains(e.target))) {
      container[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id = 'mobile-navigation'>
lorem
</div>
<div id = 'hamburger-menu-div'>
ipsem
</div>
```

another attempt:

```js
var container = document.querySelectorAll('#mobile-navigation, #hamburger-menu-div');
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  var set=0;
  for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
    if (e.target==container[i]) {
      set=1;
    }
  }
  if(set===0){
  container[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
});
//this does the same as the code below, but with two ids..
/*
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  var container = document.getElementById('mobile-navigation');
  if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
    container.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
*/
```

```html
<div id = 'mobile-navigation'>
mobile-navigation
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id = 'hamburger-menu-div'>
hamburger-menu-div
</div>
<br>
<div>
click here to close menu
</div>
```

Third attempt: Now that you have provided HTML (always better to do this), and have explained what you are trying to do, this solution should work. If it doesn't, let me know exactly what isn't good and I will fix it.

```js
//Toggle nav menu to show and hide

document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-div").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mobile-navigation");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
});


//Hide it when clicked outside

var x = document.getElementById("mobile-navigation");
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  if (!(x.contains(e.target) || e.target == document.getElementById("hamburger-menu-div"))) {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
.hamburger-menu-div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

.mobile-navigation {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 250px;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburger-menu-div" class="hamburger-menu-div">
  hamburger-menu-div
</div>


<div id="mobile-navigation" class="mobile-navigation">
  <h1> mobile nav </h1>
  <p>- Navigationpoint 1</p>
  <p>- Navigationpoint 2</p>
  <p>- Navigationpoint 3</p>
  <p>- Navigationpoint 4</p>
  <p>- Navigationpoint 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there. First thanks for your effort. No sorry. To be more clear: I have a button. That button triggers the menu to show up and to close when clicke it (through toggle class). The code I am showing here, gives me also the possibility to close the menu when clicking somewhere on the screen except the opened menu itself. The problem now is, that I want to exclude the button (hamburger-menu-div) from that code, so that when I´m clicking the button the toggle still functions. Can I exclude the code to be fired when menu is "visible" so that also toggle through the button works permanently...

Comment: Because at the moment, when I click the button, the toggle doesn´t function, as the one script displays block, none , block. And the other script tries to display none when clicked outside the menu. So here must be a conflict... :/

Comment: Its still not so clear what you want to do. Can you possibly post more code?

Comment: It would be much easier to understand with more context. You want to close a menu onclick, but not when you click on a certain element, right? If so, why do you need to get multiple ids? Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution. The problem here is, that the toggle function between display block, none, block, for my button doesn´t function then. When the nav is hidden, the button can trigger it to block, What also works then is when I click somewhere, except the button or in the nav, the menu is set to none as desired. But when the nav is opened (set to block) and click the button, the menu stays visible and doesn´t get toggled block, none, block. You can see here what I wan´t to achive siteground.com. Just go in mobile view and open close the menu via button. Also possible trough click out.

Comment: Updated the code I have so far and added yours. It seems to work here, except when I click any text in the menu, then it also disappears (it should stay). Weirdly this doesn´t function on my site?!? Why? Can I give u login data for front end so u can have a look perhaps? Thanks for support!

Comment: I should be able to look at it in 2 hours.

Comment: @Artan I just added another answer. does this work?

Comment: Hi, thanks. But it´s the same issue. When menu is opened, the toggle function for the hamburger icon (when I click it) doesn´t switch to "none". It´s so weird. Why does it function here but not at my site. I would be really glad if I could give u login data in private so you could have a look at front end and inspect the issue? I tried so many codes that seem to work here but not at my page. Would be really thankful if u could do that for me. If yes, let me know how to give you access in private talk. Still thanks for you great help until now! :)

Comment: So what are saying is it is working here but not on your website? If so, I think you should mark this answer correct. I can try to help you with your website. I'm not sure how to use SO chat. Maybe email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225419/discussion-between-sample-and-artan).